# IDirectMusicPerformance8 - MIDI only, or WAV?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to work with an old version of DirectX (8.1) and I'm finding the documentation more than a little confusing.  It feels like the `IDirectMusicPerformance8` interface is for MIDI playback, as it has various MIDI-related methods on it, but various parts of the documentation suggest that it can be used to play back WAV data as well.  For instance, the tutorial says that you call `InitAudio` on the performance, and it states "**Wave files require only a single performance channel**, and MIDI files require up to 16".

So is it for MIDI or can it be used for WAV?

If it can be used for WAV, I'm even more stumped, because I'm initializing it, running `performance->PlaySegment(segment, 0, 0, NULL)`, getting a success response, but the audio is silent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  Apparently I had been using `IDirectMusicPerformance` instead of `IDirectMusicPerformance8`, which I guess is some kind of old compatibility thing that is missing various new DirectX 8.1 methods.  Once I switched to that (along with the associated '8' versions of the loader and segment interfaces), used their new `InitAudio` and `LoadObjectFromFile` methods, called `segment->Download(performance)` before playing, then played with the new `PlaySegmentEx` method, it worked and played the WAV.